# Run application whose part of code works on targeted platfor x84 and part of it rus unchecking prefer 32

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application where I run powershell script using runspae which needs the prefer 32 option to be un checked to run and part of the c# code is using pcap.net dlls to run those I have to make target platfor as x86 which removes the option of prefer 32 bit .Pls help me in running both of them in one application

Answer (score 0):

A process will run as either a 64 bit process, or a 32 bit process. It can't be both at the same time.

Depending on your actual situation, you may be able to work around this by launching a second process from your main application. Put the code that requires 64 bit in a separate exe, that you launch from the main executable. Set the main executable to X86 only.

Obviously, this implies you may need some form of interprocess communication. There are many ways to achieve that, including files, named pipes, memory mapped files and http services. But that would be a separate question.